# set every single form readonly without using widgets in the model

Tags: django-forms

I am trying to build a template with some forms. I have a model with about 400 attributes for one entity. Now i want to make two different templates. In one Template the attributes should be listed like django form do. In the other template the attributes should be set readonly.

I don't want to create two diffent Forms for every attribute by using widgets.

```
cust_form = GeneralDataForm(instance=_customer, auto_id=False, label_suffix='')
```

I tried inserting the widget here but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

using this code you can make any form readonly. are you looking for something like this?

```
cust_form_read_only = make_form_readonly(cust_form)

def make_form_readonly(form):
        for name, field in form.fields.items():
        field.widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        field.widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
    return form
```